# Draw only part of axis in graph

Tags: graphics3d, visualization

I'm looking to draw only one half of an axis in `ContourPlot3D`, mainly because I don't wan't the axis lines to be where the interesting stuff happens (intersection of two surfaces), but I do want to show where the axes are. This is my code so far:

```
ContourPlot3D[{y == x^2, z == x^3}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -10, 10},
   AxesLabel -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0},
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3]]
```

This is the result it produces:

[image]

I would like only half of each axis to appear on the graph. I already dug through the documentation, but it seems I can only turn the axes on or off completely, no partial option. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I *think* it's not possible if you use the built-in axes.  Axes are infinite and always span the complete bounding box.  You'll have to draw your own axes.  The [CustomTicks](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) package will be very helpful in generating your own tick marks.

Comment: I believe removing axes altogether and adding your own as `Epilog` shouldn't be hard.

Comment: Yes, not easy as a general problem - approachable for a particular case. It depends on how much effort you want to put in your graphic, I believe. OTOH, I haven't checked `CustomTicks`; if someone has a free solution that fits the bill, go for it :)

Comment: I'm just throwing it in here because I wonder this myself. In the docs for `FullGraphics` it says "FullGraphics generates explicit graphics primitives for objects specified by options such as Axes, Ticks, etc." -- is there perhaps a way to extract the primitives used to draw the axes? In that case it should be straightforward to remove half of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible workaround with manual dashing

```
Show[
 ContourPlot3D[{y == x^2, z == x^3}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -10, 10},
  Boxed -> False, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5], 
  Ticks -> {-Range[3], -Range[5], Range[0, 10, 2]}, 
  AxesStyle -> {Dashing[{0.28, 0.3}], Dashing[{0.3, 0.5}], Dashing[{0, 0.25, 0.5}]}, 
  TicksStyle -> Dashing[{}]],
 Graphics3D[{Text[x, {-3.4, 0, 0}, BaseStyle -> Large], 
  Text[y, {0, -5.5, 0}, BaseStyle -> Large], 
  Text[z, {0, 0, 11.5}, BaseStyle -> Large]}]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Alright, now how could I put labels on those axes (preferably at/near the ends)?

Comment: @JimboBimbo You can add `Text` with explicit positions, see my update.

Comment: Ok, that does indeed help. But this solution is odd, because when I rotate the graph, the lengths of the axes seem to change arbitrarily, becoming longer and shorter. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my machine, or something else. They appear in most of the desired side, but shrink and stretch on the other side as I turn it around.

Comment: @JimboBimbo Yes, you need to change the dashing parameters for different points of view. It is just a workaround. Strictly speaking you need a package like CustomTicks as Szabolcs wrote in comments.

Answer (score 0):

It is not by chance that `ContourPlot3D` defaults to `Boxed->True`. It leaves the surfaces away from the axes.

You can then add other axes or wherever you like.
Below, the x and y axes are projected onto the x y plane.  I find this a bit helpful for conveying that (0,0,0) is somewhere in the center of the box.

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[{y == x^2, z == x^3}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 
   5}, {z, -10, 10},
  BaseStyle -> 16, BoxStyle -> Directive[Dashed, GrayLevel[.25]], 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic,
  Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3]],
 Graphics3D[{Thickness[.005], Dashed, Blue, 
   Line[{{-3, 0, -10}, {5, 0, -10}}], 
   Line[{{0, -5, -10}, {0, 5, -10}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, but is it possible to add ticks and numbers to those lines so they look like axes?

Comment: You can easily add ticks and numbers using `Table`.